# mysqli_fetch_array --> update an input based on 2 input fields

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I have a list of products to be ordered and I want to set the 'to order' field to be the 'minimum' minus the 'stock' whenever 'stock' is changed, but only the last input is working. For the rest of them, the `onchange` doesn't work.

```
  $result_producten = mysqli_query($conn, 
                                 "SELECT * FROM producten "
                                  ."WHERE lev_id = '".$sql_result2['id']."'"
                                  );

     <table width="600" border="1" cellpadding"1" cellspacing= "1" class="flatTable">
        <tr class="headingTr">
            <th>Suppliercode</th>
            <th>Product</th>
            <th>Stock</th>
            <th>Minimum</th>
            <th>To order</th>
        </tr>
    <?php
        while ($producten=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_producten)) {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>".$producten['lev_id']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$producten['productnaam']."</td>";
            echo "<td>
                  <input id='test' name='".$producten['id']."' 
                         type='text' onchange='myFunction(this.value)' 
                         onkeypress='return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57'
                  />
                  </td>";
            echo "<td>".$producten['minimum']."</td>";
            echo "<td>
                  <input id='".$producten['id']."' name='mytext' 
                         type='text' readonly='true' />
                  </td>";
            echo "</tr>";
?>
<script>
function myFunction(val) {
    var elem = document.getElementById('<?php echo $producten['id']; ?>');
elem.value = val;


}
</script>
<?php
        }

?>
    </table>
```

Then I want to create a form that contains all the products that have 'To order' > 0.

How can I get the `onchange` working for every product and how can I create that form once the 'stock' is put in for all the products?

Comment: I don't see where you're using `mysqli_fetch_array()`

Comment: @JayBlanchard "while($producten=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_producten))"

Comment: One is `fetch_array` one is `fetch_assoc`.

Comment: Does it care if I use array or assoc? It has no impact on the output of the table. Thanks for the fast replies (:

Comment: Wait a second please. The code I given you guys wasnt the code I ended with. Im trying to recode it to my last version again.
There was something that the javascript getElementById($THEIDFROMTHEPRODUCT) and the input id was also $THEIDFROMTHEPRODUCT .

Comment: I changed the code back to old.

Comment: @StanvanderAvoird, I made a major edit to your question. Feel free to edit further if I got anything wrong. But, your question was too long. There was a lot of irrelevant information that (in my opinion) made it less clear what you were asking for. Also, you have two separate questions. The first one is about your javascript not working. The second one (how to create the form) should probably be a different question on here because 'how to create a form' is not relevant to 'my onchange is not working'

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're printing `myFunction` multiple times. Try doing this instead:

```
while (){
  // bunch of code
echo "<td>
      <input id='test' name='".$producten['id']."' type='text'
    //notice the difference in the onchange code
          onchange='myFunction(this.value,this.name)' 
          onkeypress='return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57'/>
                  </td>";
  //more code
}
```

then BELOW the `while`:

```
<script>
function myFunction(val,id){
    document.getElementById(id).value = val;
}
</script>
```

As far as creating the form based on the inputs with stock > 0, you will need to submit a form (wrap your table in a form) and on the PHP side, get all the submitted values and build an array of product IDs to show on the next page. Then do a mysql query like:

```
SELECT * FROM producten WHERE product_id IN (1,5,86,19457,376)
```

where `1,5,86,19457,376` are your product ids to look up.
Then loop through the results and show the products however you want. Furthermore, to do this, you will need to change the input names to something like `<input name="mytext[]">` which will submit an array of your values under `$_POST['mytext']`. You may want to use another input with the product ID or something to submit along with `mytext`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Its working now.

Only one more question is left.
How can I create a form (for example with Form Action or a database input) with an overview of all products you have set a value > 0.
So once I click on the submit button, I want a next page showing all the products where the value of 'To order' input is greater than zero.

Thanks alot again (:!

Comment: @StanvanderAvoird, I updated my answer to include some info about creating the form.

Comment: Thanks for your reply again.
You said : 'you will need to submit a form (wrap your table in a form)'.
Well thats my problem now. I dont know how to submit a form by using a WHILE function. Please watch this specific question written here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30682237/create-an-overview-form-from-the-products-that-were-ordered

Thanks alot (: