# Create a submit form (wrap the table into a form and show it as a table again) from the products that were ordered

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

**EDIT:** Maybe its easier to create a new column in the database. Named: to_order. 
Then create an UPDATE Query for each product . Something like : UPDATE products SET to_order = '[VALUE_INPUT]' WHERE id = '[ID_PRODUCT]'
The problem here is, where to excecute this query? How can I define the VALUE_INPUT and ID_PRODUCT for each row?

If this works, and I can UPDATE each row for that specific product etc.
I can easily create a mysqli_fetch_assoc again where only the [Product_name],[to_order] will be given.
Please help.

---

I'm working on a supplier order system. Where the manager of the restaurant can easily select a supplier, fill in how much stock he has now of that specific product. And it will automatically calculate how much you need to order.

This part is done.But now, once we fill in the form I want to get an overview of all products you need to order, and it needs to be printable.

For example in words explained:

- We have some columns in our table [ID_product][ID_supplier][Product_name][Stock][Minimum][To_order]
- ID_product, ID_supplier, Product_name and Minimum are all data from the database. Stock is what you need to fill in. And To_order is calculated by : Minimum-stock = To_order. (logic)
- With a mysql_fetch_assoc command we can show all specific products with its specific id and minimum integer.
- ***Now here is the part where my question is:*** Once everything is filled in, you need to click a button that refers to a next page. On this page your total input is shown, a full list. 
  Like: [Product_name][To_order]

So on this page you get an overview of your form where you filled in all these values. So you get a list (how big depends on how much products you have in your database) with all the calculated inputs from 'To_order'.

My problem is, if I create a Form Action into my fetch_assoc, it can read all element names, but as soon you submit the form and go to the next page. All the data is lost.
I need something where I can see the value from the previous page of that input. And then for all specific products.

My **form.php** (Where I need to fill in my stock in order to calculate the 'To_order' input). This is working fine.

```
    <table width="600" border="1" cellpadding"1" cellspacing= "1" class="flatTable">
                                <tr class="headingTr">
                                    <th>
                                        Supplier code
                                    </th>
                                    <th>
                                        Product
                                    </th>
                                        <th>
                                        Stock
                                    </th>

                                        <th>
                                        Minimum
                                    </th>

                                        <th>
                                        To order
                                    </th>
                                </tr>


                                <?php


                                while ($producten=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_producten)) {
                                    echo "<tr>";
                                    echo "<td><form method='POST' action='lijst.php'><label name='".$producten['lev_id']."'>".$producten['lev_id']."</label></td>";
                                    echo "<td><label name='".$producten['productnaam']."'>".$producten['productnaam']."</label></td>";

                                        echo "<td>
      <input id='".$producten['minimum']."' name='".$producten['id']."' type='text' 
         oninput='calculateBestelling(this.value,this.name, this.id)' 
          onkeypress='return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57'/>
                  </td>";
                                    echo "<td><input id='".$producten['minimum']."' name='mytext2'  type='text' readonly='true' value='".$producten['minimum']."' /></td>";

                                    echo "<td><input id='".$producten['id']."' name='order[]' type='text' readonly='true'  /></td>";


                                    echo "</tr>";



                                }


                                ?>

<script>
var minimum;
var stock;
var order;
function calculateBestelling(val,name,id){
    minimum = document.getElementById(id).id;
    stock =  document.getElementById(id).value;
    document.getElementById(name).value = minimum - val;
    order = document.getElementById(name).value;

    if (order < 0) {


    document.getElementById(name).value = '0';
   }

}


</script>
                            </table>
                                    <p><input type='submit'/></p></form>
```

Then the next page (where the overview needs to be shown):

```
<header>
                        <h2>Complete order form - Supplier: (HERE THE SUPPLIER)</h2>

                    </header>
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="row">

                            <table width="600" border="1" cellpadding"1" cellspacing= "1" class="flatTable">
                                <tr class="headingTr">
                                    <th>
                                        Product
                                    </th>
                                    <th>
                                        To order
                                    </th>

                                </tr>


                                <?php
                            //And I dont know what I need to do here. I want the values from the 3rd input the previous file. But how I can combine this with each row for a specific product?

                                while ($producten=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_producten)) {
                                    echo "<tr>";
                                    echo "<td>PRODUCT HERE</td>";

                                    echo "<td><input id='toorder' name='order[]' type='text' readonly='true' value='(THE VALUE OF THE PREVIOUS FILE FOR THAT PRODUCT)' /></td>";


                                    echo "</tr>";


                                }


                                ?>

                            </table>



                        </div>
                    </div>
```

I created an image, where you simple can see what I have in my mind.
URL TO IMAGE: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6AnTl.png

So we also need to check something like : if (!to_order > 0) { DONT SHOW ROW }

Feel free to change codes, maybe some other way that works? Like staying on the same page, and hide the stock and minimum values. So we only can see the ID's, Product names and To_order values?

Comment: You can either use PHP sessions to store the data for form1, or create form2 with hidden fields containing the value for form1. Let us know if you have issues with either one of these approaches.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How can I save a bunch of data in a PHP session that is still linked to a specific product? For example. if you store the value of the To_order input in a PHP session. How is it then possible to assign the correct value to the specific product?

Comment: @crafter I answered you with a question

Comment: @crafter I answered you with a question again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours trying I finally figured it out.
I used $_SESSIONS to store data in. Thats one thing.
Then, made sure that the inputs are all array.

```
while ($producten=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_producten)) {
                                    echo "<form method='POST' action='verwerken.php'><tr>";
                                    echo "<td><input name='ids[]' type='text' readonly='true' value='".$producten['id']."' /></td>";
                                    echo "<td><input name='lev_id' type='text' readonly='true' value='".$producten['lev_id']."' /></td>";
                                    echo "<td><input name='producten[]' type='text' readonly='true' value='".$producten['productnaam']."' /></td>";


                                       echo "<td>
      <input tabindex='1' id='".$producten['minimum']."' name='".$producten['id']."' type='text' 
         oninput='calculateBestelling(this.value,this.name, this.id)' 
          onkeypress='return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57'/>
                  </td>";
                                    echo "<td><input id='".$producten['minimum']."'  type='text' readonly='true' value='".$producten['minimum']."' /></td>";

                                    echo "<td><input id='".$producten['id']."' name='test[]' type='text' readonly='true'  /></td>";


                                    echo "</tr>";

 }
```

This is the while for the table.
Once you filled in all your STOCK values, it will automatically calculate the value to order.
Thats working fine. Now when you click the submit button a next page will be openend.
This page only inserts a query into a database.
For every row it will update the to_order value in the database.

```
$order_test = $_SESSION['hoeveelheid'] =$_POST['test'];
    $ids_test = $_POST['ids'];
        $producten = $_SESSION['product'] = $_POST['producten'];

    foreach (array_combine($producten, $order_test) as $producten => $order_test) {

    echo 'Product: ' . $producten . ' - Te  bestellen: ' . $order_test.'<br>';
     mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE producten SET bestellen = '".$order_test."' WHERE productnaam ='".$producten."'");

}

    $_SESSION['lev_id'] = $_POST['lev_id'];
    $_SESSION['check'] = 'true';
header('Location: bestelformulier.php');
exit();

        }
```

If the database is not that slow, you should not see this page.
After the query is done, you will be redirected to the overview page.
Bestelformulier.php.

Here you simply mysqli_fetch_assoc the values from the database again. And you have an updated form.

Thanks everyone for the help (:

Answer (score 0):

Web pages are stateless, in other words, each request is separate to the web server. Because of this there is no link between two requests, for example form1 and form2.

In order to overcome this, you must use some form of storage that will persist across two (or more separate requests). This is called persistent storage. For long term persistent storage, use databases. For short term, use PHP sessions. You can read up on PHP sessions [in the PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php).

To store your values from form 1, save the values into session.
In your form, you will point your form action to form1.php

form1_view.php:

```
<form action=<?php echo "form1.php" method="post">
   <input name="field1">
   <input type="form1_submit">
</form>
```

and your form input handler is form1.php

```
   if (isset($_POST['form1_submit']) {
      session_start();
      $_SESSION['form1_inputs'] = serialize($_POST);
   }
```

Then, when receiving the valued from form2, retrieve the values you stored from form1.

form2_view.php:

```
<form action=<?php echo "form2.php" method="post">
   <input name="field2">
   <input type="form2_submit">
</form>
```

Form2 is handled by its own handler.
form2.php

```
   if (isset($_POST['form2_submit']) {
      session_start();
      $form1_values = unserialize($_SESSION['form1_inputs']);
      $form2_values = $_POST;

      // combine input from both forms into one variable.
      $all_form_values = array_merge($form1_values, $form2_values)

      // You can now save values from both forms. How you do this
      // ...will depend on how you save the values. This is an example.
      save_my_values($all_form_values); 
   }
```

Comment: I am sorry but I don't  get it. When I submit form1 (the form where the 3rd input is calculated) it will submit me to the next page, the list.
At this file I will put your first code right?
But where to put the second one? Because on that page I need to show everything. A full list of products and what you need to order.
I also dont know how to convert the arrays into tables, so that it will combine the right value input to the right product.

Comment: I have expanded my examples to address you initial request "I need something where I can see the value from the previous page of that input.". It appears as if you have other issues besides this related to how to process forms with PHP and I suggest you do further reading and testing. I cannot help you with this.

Comment: Hmm.. I know how it works, the sessions with the data. 
I saved the suppliers name in a session, and requested it on the next page. Thats working.
But now with the product + to_order values.

I found something but can't figure out how to use it in my way.
Something with:
 while(list($key, $val) = each($_REQUEST))
For each item in the post from the order.php put the values to a key/val list pair.
Soo you will get: 
Quanitity ----- Item
1                    strawberry
3                    banana

Comment: I will give you a link: http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/58320-php-a-dynamically-created-order-form-and-receipt-emailed-to-owner/